# What is wrong with my xpath? Why is a different element receiving the click?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Steps to recreate:

1. Go to http://practice.automationtesting.in/
2. Click on add to basket
3. Then view basket
4. Change the quantity to 2
5. Click on Update Basket
6. Click on remove item'X'
7. Or use coupon code "krishnasakinala"
8. Click on Apply Coupon button

The error I am getting is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a href="http://practice.automationtesting.in/basket/?remove_item=b73ce398c39f506af761d2277d853a92&amp;_wpnonce=cd1b3aea3e" class="remove" title="Remove this item" data-product_id="160" data-product_sku="">...</a> is not clickable at point (216, 220). Other element would receive the click:
```

I have tried different locators but getting the same error.

Read more: https://softwaretestingboard.com/q2a/4041/exceptions-elementclickinterceptedexception-intercepted#ixzz6iUxRC97y

My code:

```
url = "http://practice.automationtesting.in"
driver.get(url)
wait_timeout = 5
wait_variable = W(driver, wait_timeout)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-product_id='160']").click()
wait_variable.until(E.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class ='added_to_cart wc-forward']"))).click()

wait_variable.until(E.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='number']"))).clear()
wait_variable.until(E.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='number']"))).send_keys(2)

wait_variable.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "update_cart"))).click()
wait_variable.until(E.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Remove this item']"))).click()
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you used? Provide a [mre] please.

Comment: Please also add the import statements. Please carefully see [how I have edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65551529/revisions) your question and add ``` before and after your pasted code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem like making the driver wait, using a different element identifier (CSS/class/etc.) but the most effective one is to use the method `execute_script()`

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('the xpath of the element')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: This worked without any errors `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Remove this item']"))))
`

Comment: This is red flag in testing , don't use it . you are skipping UI functionality and directly triggering click event on the element

Answer (score 0):

```
wait_variable.until(E.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.NAME, "update_cart"))).click()

wait_variable.until(E.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[class="blockUI blockOverlay"]')))

wait_variable.until(E.staleness_of(
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="blockUI blockOverlay"]')))

wait_variable.until(E.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Remove this item']"))).click()
```

The error is due to the overlay loader use this code , using javascript to click an element is not a right way it will bypass the UI rendering and direcly trigger click event on the element.

This should be avoided if you are using selenium for testing

**How to find locator for overlay loader:**

what is overlay loader :

[image]

This spinner is a UI element used to block user interaction with UI while ajax components are being loaded in the background.

**What are the challenges:**?

The spinner load so fast that it is hard to locate the element from dev tool

**How to find the locator**?

open element tab , right click the html and seelct break on sub tree modification

[image]

**now click play button:**

click update cart and click the blue play button till the loader is present in the UI.

[image]

This will freeze UI with the spiner in screen , now you can easily find the locator

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Will try it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. You helped me learn a very important concept.

Comment: @ratnasinha could you accept the answer by clicking the tick sign near to my answer